# NAudio WaveFileReader - Invalid WAV file

Tags: c#, naudio

```
WaveFileReader wf = new WaveFileReader((filepathOpen));
```

`Invalid WAV file` - No fmt chunk found

Exception occur. Please help.

Comment: could be the related to the problem I noticed and described in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713809/4932122
checking the wave file with a hex editor might give some insight why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have attempted to open an invalid WAV file, or maybe a file that isn't a WAV file at all. (e.g. you can't open an MP3 file with `WaveFileReader`)

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error while trying to read a `.wav` file with `AudioFileReader` any ideas about what I can do?