# Convert an audio file to 8000Hz 16Bit Mono Wav in UWP

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, pcm, wave

How to convert an audio file to 8000Hz 16Bit Mono Wav in UWP C# to be used in ACRcloud UWP SDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has been answered here before.

You can use NAudio (I think it should work in UWP, but you need to check as 1.8 version was a bit restricted in UWP. There is an update, but I do not know if it has the necessary classes).

You could also check **Bass audio library** as it is available for C#, if NAudio will not work.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35824819/convert-a-wav-file-to-8000hz-16bit-mono-wav) for an example.

Comment: NAudio for UWP doesn't support this but how to do that with Bass audio library as it can be worked with UWP

Comment: Check ManagedBass. It is a .net wrapper for Bass. I think you are looking for WaveFileWriter. You can find it here: https://managedbass.github.io/api/ManagedBass.WaveFileWriter.html). There is also another one: BASS.NET, but it is not free for commercial use.

Comment: to convert to WAV file, with **attributes A-Law, 8000Hz, 64kbps, mono.**?